# How to use await without using async

Tags: python, function, async-await, discord

await can not be used unless async is written before def.
Please let me know if there is a way to use await without using async.

```
def check_queue(id):
    if queues[id] != []:
        music_state[id] = "On"
        del music_list[id][0]
        del queue_list[id][0]
        player = queues[id].pop(0)
        players[id] = player
        player.start()
        await client.send_message(message.channel, "Next") # <----
```

Comment: [Read this](https://www.aeracode.org/2018/02/19/python-async-simplified/) - It covers what you've asked and more.

Comment: Generally you can't do this because `client` requires an authenticated connection with the discord API, which is provided when you use `client.run`.  Even if you could run the above code outside the event loop, sending the message would fail because the bot is not logged in.